# How to properly achieve dynamic parallel action with a declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkinsfile

Currently, I'm going to need an implementation that must find all files within a directory and start a parallel task for every file found.

Is it possible to achieve this using declarative pipelines?

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("test") {
            steps {
                dir ("file_path") {
                    // find all files with complete path
                    parallel (
                        // execute parallel tasks for each file found.
                        // this must be dynamic
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I do if i want to run multiple steps sequentaly and not parallel?

Comment: Sure, but that way you cannot generate the parallel tasks dynamically, for example, depending on some files on the repository.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Managed to solve it with the following code:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label "master"}
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def tests = [:]
                    for (f in findFiles(glob: '**/html/*.html')) {
                        tests["${f}"] = {
                            node {
                                stage("${f}") {
                                    echo '${f}'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    parallel tests
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also check out the official Pipeline examples - https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#parallel-multiple-nodes

Comment: @phedoreanu i'm using declarative pipeline...

Comment: @phedoreanu I have rejected your edit, editing code should have good reasons, your comment isn't enough for me to allow an edit of this kind on an answer which was a self solution. I think you should have commented to discuss the matter with the answer author before doing this edit.

Comment: @phedoreanu I you think you have a better derivative work, then please write your own answer and explain why it is better (in error handling, templates, etc.) instead.

Comment: Hi, I figured out the same after a few failing attempts. My only problem right now is that if I put two stage{..} sections inside a node for some reasons the workflow stage chart and Blu Ocean get confused. For instance in the workflow stage chart I get NaNy NaNd and in Blue Ocean I get only the first stage.

Comment: How would you limit this for, let's say 10 concurrents builds running at once ?

Answer (score 14):

This also works, if you want to stay within the `Declarative Pipeline` space

```
// declare our vars outside the pipeline
def tests = [:]
def files

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // we've declared the variable, now we give it the values
                    files = findFiles(glob: '**/html/*.html')
                    // Loop through them
                    files.each { f ->
                        // add each object from the 'files' loop to the 'tests' array
                        tests[f] = {
                            // we're already in the script{} block, so do our advanced stuff here
                            echo f.toString()
                        }
                    }
                    // Still within the 'Script' block, run the parallel array object
                    parallel tests
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to allocate each parallel task to different Jenkins nodes then simply wrap the actions in a `node {}` block, like this:

`tests[f] = {
    node {
        echo f.toString()
    }
}`

Answer (score 7):

Be aware, that dynamic build steps could cause some problems in some build steps, e.g. when you call an other job:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def tests = [:]
                    for (f in findFiles(glob: '**/html/*.html')) {
                        // Create temp variable, otherwise the name will be the last value of the for loop
                        def name = f
                        tests["${name}"] = {
                            build job: "${name}"
                        }
                    }
                    parallel tests
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but i used stage and echo inside tests, but it will giving stage name and echo as null until I used a local variable like you have used name above. Do you know why that is? Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to use scripted Pipelines to do this since you can use arbitrary Groovy, but you should still be able to do this with declarative Pipelines using the [`findFiles`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-findfiles-code-find-files-in-the-workspace) step.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where you can setup the maximum number of concurrent tasks running at once with `collate(n)`.

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage("Parallel") {
      steps {
        script {
          def list = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon", "zeta", "eta", "theta", "iota", "kappa"]

          // Split the list into batches of 4
          def parallelBatches = list.collate(4);
          // [["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"], ["epsilon", "zeta", "eta", "theta"], ["iota", "kappa"]]

          // This allows to run a maximum of 4 tasks in parallel (at once)
          for (parallelBatch in parallelBatches) {
            def tasks = [:]

            for (task in parallelBatch) {
              tasks["${task}"] = {
                stage("${task}") {
                  echo '${task}'
                }
              }
            }
            parallel tasks

            // Once the batch is over, the outer loop move onto the next batch
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```